# ODE, transforming

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Try to find a solution of the ODE  $x'= \frac{x-t+2}{2x+t+1} +5 $

I found a solution but do anyone see a easier solution?

Define $ f(\frac{x-t+2}{2x+t+1}):= \frac{x-t+2}{2x+t+1} +5$

First i search $ (x_0, t_0): x_0-t_0+2=0, 2x_0+t_0+1=0$

The solution is: $x_0=-1, t_0=1$

So i do the transformation: $ y=x+1, s=t-1$ and get $y'=f(\frac{y-s}{2y+s})= \frac{y-s}{2y+s}+5= \frac{11y+4s}{2y+s} $

Next i define $\overline{f} (\frac{y}{s}):= \frac{11 \frac{y}{s} + 4}{2 \frac{y}{s} +1}$ and do the transformation $u=\frac{y}{s}$, i get $ u'= \frac{- u + \overline{f}(u)}{s}= \frac{1}{s}* [ - u + \frac{11 u + 4}{2u+1}]= \frac{1}{s} [ \frac{- 2u^2 -u+11u+4}{2u+1}]= \frac{1}{s}[\frac{-2u^2 + 10 u +4}{2u+1}]$

Now it is seperable: $\int \frac{2u+1}{- 2u^2 + 10 u + 4} du= \int \frac{1}{s} ds$

I calculate the integrals on my paper  and subsitute u=y/s and y,s - but is there a easier transformation, so that i doesn´t have so difficult integrals?

Comment: Most probably , the answer to your last question is No. Had there been any other easier General method , it must had been given in the textbooks, or had been taught to us before this method was taught. And you are finding it difficult to solve the integration!!.  Just imagine, if you had not been taught the above technique of homogenisaton, could you even have solved the differential equation (Leave alone integrating)?? To have a result ,there isn't always a shortcut.

Comment: Hei Moo, I exactly do this method in my entry?